# Error when downloading an account restricted file from Google drive with wget. I get the error of "Result too large"

Tags: wget

How do you download a file from Google drive with wget?

The file I want to download is account restricted meaning only a person with a particular Google account can access the file. (i.e. the file has been set to restricted by right clicking it and clicking share and choosing the option so only a particular google account email address can access it, so only a person logged in as that person can access it)

And in this particular situation, setting the file to "everyone" is not really an option for me. (why, is another matter!). I know that if the file is set to "everyone" then wget can download it.

I log into my Google account, the one that as access to the file, and I go to  Google.com were I am logged in, and using the cookie editor extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-editor/hlkenndednhfkekhgcdicdfddnkalmdm    I export the cookie to the clipboard, paste it into a file in notepad and save it.

```
C:\blah>wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies .\cook.txt url
```

I get an error  of  "result too large" (same error as if I were to try to try that command without --load-cookies .\cook.txt

First of all, if I were to set it to everyone, (which i'm doing just as a temporary test), then it works

```
O:\abc>wget --no-check-certificate https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fo...YB/view?usp=sharing
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2022-10-15 09:27:59--  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f...YB/view?usp=sharing
Resolving drive.google.com... 142.250.187.238
Connecting to drive.google.com|142.250.187.238|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify drive.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `view@usp=sharing.1'

    [ <=>                                                                                               ] 67,696      --.-K/s   in 0.02s

2022-10-15 09:27:59 (4.01 MB/s) - `view@usp=sharing.1' saved [67696]
```

Notice there is a warning "WARNING: cannot verify drive.google.com's certificate," but it doesn't matter I can still download it.

No error saying "result too large".
So the issue is specifically when the file is restricted.

And it's not a huge file, the file is only 78MB. So file size isn't the/an/ issue / anything to do with any issue.

If the file is set restricted to only a particular gmail account, then if it's possible to download with wget, i'd have to load cookies. And i've made a cookie/cookies file, in the manner I described. And then tried running wget with it, but it doesn't work. And infact even if I do wget without --load-cookies, I get the same error of "result too large".

```
O:\abc>dir cook.txt
 Volume in drive O is TOSHIBA EXT
 Volume Serial Number is E05E-F917

 Directory of O:\abc

15/10/2022  09:15             8,699 cook.txt
               1 File(s)          8,699 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  3,946,736,459,776 bytes free
```

and I run the command

```
O:\abc>wget --load-cookies .\cook.txt https://drive.google.com/file/d/1.....YB/view?usp=sharing
```

The output looks largely the same as if I ad done the command without --load-cookies .\cook.txt

```
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
--2022-10-15 09:39:12--  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f...B/view?usp=sharing
Resolving drive.google.com... 142.250.187.238
Connecting to drive.google.com|142.250.187.238|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify drive.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fo7.....YB/view?usp%3Dsharing&followup=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f....YB/view?usp%3Dsharing [foll
owing]
--2022-10-15 09:39:12--  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://drive.google.com/file
/d/1f....zYB/view?usp%3Dsharing&followup=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1....YB/view?usp%
3Dsharing
Resolving accounts.google.com... 142.250.200.13
Connecting to accounts.google.com|142.250.200.13|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify accounts.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S-33.....71&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%
2Fd%2F1.....YB%2Fview%3Fusp%3Dsharing&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd.....p%3Dsharing&osid=1&passive=1209600&service=wise&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AQD.....0yX_P [following]
--2022-10-15 09:39:13--  https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?dsh=S-33.....71&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.goo
gle.com%2Ffil.....w%3Fusp%3Dsharing&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1fo7RdB68
uFZ27nIHJCffMPgzXSlcOzYB%2Fview%3Fusp%3Dsharing&osid=1&passive=1209600&service=wise&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AQDHY
Wq.....iRl0yX_P
Reusing existing connection to accounts.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
identifier@dsh=S-33....871&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1fo7RdB...zYB%2Fview%3
Fusp=sharing&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1fo....OzYB%2Fview%3Fusp=sharing&osid=1&passive=1209
600&service=wise&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AQD....c9fFNx458..R1XjInhWResi7WO..Rl0
yX_P: No such file or directory

Cannot write to `identifier@dsh=S-332...0%3A1...871&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F....gz
XSlc..2Fview%3Fusp=sharing&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Ffile%2Fd%2F1f....HJCff..XSlcOzYB%2Fview%3Fusp=sharing&os
id=1&passive=12..&service=wise&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&ifkv=AQDHYW.....InhW
Resi7WO....yX_P' (Result too large).
```

The errors and warnings from that output are

```
WARNING: cannot verify drive.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3':
      Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
......
    WARNING: cannot verify accounts.google.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=Google Trust Services LLC/CN=GTS CA 1C3':
      Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
............
 No such file or directory
   
    Cannot write to `identifier@dsh
.......
(Result too large).
```

How can I get it downloaded with wget?

I haven't tested curl yet but this question is with wget.

**ADDED**

Slight correction.. Even when the link is to everyone, what actually downloads is just a 65KB file  with HTML/Javascript contents.

```
O:\abc>dir
 Volume in drive O is TOSHIBA EXT
 Volume Serial Number is E05E-F917

 Directory of O:\abc

...
15/10/2022  09:27            67,695 view@usp=sharing
....
O:\abc>

O:\abc>file "view@usp=sharing"
view@usp=sharing: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines (16533)

O:\abc>
```

There is a program called gdown https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown  that can download a google drive link though from what I can tell, you can't pass it a cookie and download a file that only specific gmail accounts can access.

Some more info

This might be a way to a solution though I haven't tested it yet https://medium.com/@acpanjan/download-google-drive-files-using-wget-3c2c025a8b99    a possible source is this link from a page of a user called "iamtekeste" https://gist.github.com/iamtekeste/3cdfd0366ebfd2c0d805  from a commenter called beliys

The medium link mentions  rearranging the URL from e.g.

`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UibyVC_C2hoT_XEw15gPEwPW4yFyJFeOEA/view?usp=sharing`

(moving the file ID),

to

```
https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID
```

Then wget works.. And then one can try with loading cookies, for a file that requires logging into a google account, not tested yet though.

I notice that the suggestion at the medium link involves a command line that as $(..) , bash style command substitution, so since bash is more easily a linux thing than a windows thing,  I tested the command suggested there in ubuntu.

https://medium.com/@acpanjan/download-google-drive-files-using-wget-3c2c025a8b99

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

When the file is accessible to all, then it downloads it.

When the file isn't accessible to all, then it downloads an HTML file that is 139KB and is a Google login page.  The same page you get in a web browser if you tried to access the file and weren't logged in

That "iamtekeste" page on github has a comment from LL3RD  that mentions  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312867/how-to-download-large-file-from-google-drive-from-terminal-gdown-doesnt-work  that I haven't tried yet but will try

Comment: Might help https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2011-09/msg00019.html

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio absolutely not, read the question, there is no issue with file size, as I said. (and there's no issue with filename length either).